# a problem with file handling in c fgetc() after fputc()

Tags: c, file

I have a text file with the filename `in.txt`, which has the following content:

```
1111
1100
0000
```

I am attempting to change the content of this file with the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    FILE *fp = fopen( "in.txt", "r+" );

    fseek( fp, 6, SEEK_CUR );
    fputc( '1', fp );
    printf( "%c", fgetc( fp ) );

    fclose( fp );
}
```

After running this program, the 3<sup>rd</sup> character on line 2 of the text file has changed to the character code `0` (not the character code for the digit `'0'`, which would be `48` in ASCII).

Why is this happening?

Since the only character that I am writing to the file is the character code for the digit `1`, how is it possible that one of the characters in the file is being overwritten with a completely different character?

Comment: Please put code and errors directly in the post, not as linked images.

Comment: Why do you have a `.cpp` extension for a C program? That's usually for C++.

Comment: You never use `rbuf`, what is it for?

Comment: You may want to read this: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12149471)

Comment: Since you did not fix the question yourself, I have typed the necessary parts of the code from the image and inserted them into the question, and explained what was shown in the image. I have also reformulated the entire question. If you do not feel happy with my formulation, feel free to change it.

Comment: ty so much . its help a lot ..

Comment: Add output and compiler error.

Comment: @AbhishekMane: There is no compiler error. The question is not describing a compile-time problem. Also, the output to `stdout` is not the issue. The problem is what is written to the file. This has been described exactly in the question. I don't think it is appropriate to attempt to post the file contents after being written to, because a null character cannot be easily shown. Therefore, the textual description of what exactly is happening seems better.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When opening a file in `"r+"` update mode, you open the file for both reading and writing.

However, this does not mean that you can freely switch between reading and writing. According to [§7.21.5.3 ¶7 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.3p7), there are certain restrictions:

- Output cannot be followed by input without an intervening call to `fflush` or to a file positioning function (`fseek`, `fsetpos` or `rewind`).
- Input cannot be followed by output without an intervening call to a file positioning function, unless the input operation encountered end-of-file.

In your posted code, you are violating the first rule, which has the consequence that your program is invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). This means that anything may happen, including the possibility that your I/O functions are reading or writing nonsense (which seems to be happening in your case).

The simplest solution to your problem would probably be to add a call to `fflush` between the call to `fputc` and `fgetc`.

Comment: You have your `X cannot be followed by Y` backwards.

Comment: @Barmar: You were right. Thanks for pointing it out. I believe I have fixed it now.